# Unable to install Free Lets Encrypt SSL on AWS EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

Im unable to install free lets encrypt SSL on AWS EC2 new instance for a domain.

[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto

[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ chmod a+x certbot-auto

[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ sudo ./certbot-auto --debug -v --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory certonly -d domainname.com

Error showing like this -

Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system.
Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot cannot be installed.
Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.

Here is the server details

````
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga```

Pls help how to install and use?
````

Comment: Im using "Amazon Linux AMI" NOT "Amazon Linux AMI 2" I have followed this but not worked actually.